# How to compare date in Batch script

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a text file which contains a date (the format would be like 1/1/2015 or 01/01/2015... both formats are acceptable).

Now I have to write a batch script which will compare dates.  It has to show that the dates 1/1/2015 and 01/01/2015 are the same.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do the contents of the file look like, exactly?

Comment: Is that month/day/year or day/month/year?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not the most elegant way, but in the interest of getting you a working sample - this performs the comparison you need:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM Dates to compare.
REM Change the values here to test the results.
SET Date1=1/8/2015
SET Date2=01/08/2015

REM Break apart by slashes.
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%A IN ("%Date1%") DO (
    SET Month1=00%%A
    SET Day1=00%%B
    SET Year1=20%%C

    REM Pad by taking the last chars from the right.
    SET Month1=!Month1:~-2!
    SET Day1=!Day1:~-2!
    SET Year1=!Year1:~-4!
)
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%A IN ("%Date2%") DO (
    SET Month2=00%%A
    SET Day2=00%%B
    SET Year2=20%%C

    SET Month2=!Month2:~-2!
    SET Day2=!Day2:~-2!
    SET Year2=!Year2:~-4!
)

REM Perform comparisions.
IF /I "%Month1%" NEQ "%Month2%" GOTO NoMatch
IF /I "%Day1%" NEQ "%Day2%" GOTO NoMatch
IF /I "%Year1%" NEQ "%Year2%" GOTO NoMatch

REM If we get here, a match was found.
ECHO The dates are the same.
GOTO :EOF

:NoMatch
ECHO The dates are different.

ENDLOCAL
```

This sample could easily be used as a subroutine which takes in `Date1` and `Date2` as variables and then sets a return variable for use in the main program.

Note that the order of month or day doesn't matter as far as the script is concerned. `Month1` could just as easily be named `Date1Part1` (etc.) and the script would work just fine.

Comment: I don't think this will work for `08` vs. `8`.  I believe `01` vs. `1` works because they get compared as numbers, but `08` doesn't work because the zero prefix means "octal", but `08` is not valid octal, so I think it compares as string, and therefore think they differ.

Comment: @TripeHound - You are correct. I updated the sample to pad the values so they will be compared as strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

This method use a subroutine that allows you to compare two dates with any comparison of `if` command, like `leq`, `gtr`, etc.

```
@echo off

call :CompareDates 1/1/2015 equ 01/01/2015
if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
   echo Dates are equal
) else (
   echo Dates are different
)
goto :EOF


:CompareDates date1 comparison date2
for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=/" %%a in ("%1/%3") do (
   set /A m1=10%%a,d1=10%%b,y1=%%c, m2=10%%d,d2=10%%e,y2=%%f
)
if %y1%%m1:~-2%%d1:~-2% %2 %y2%%m2:~-2%%d2:~-2% exit /B 0
exit /B 1
```

This code assume that the date format is MM/DD/YYYY. If your date format is different, just change the `m1`,`d1`,`m2`,`d2` variables in the `set /A` command with the proper order.