# Testing for passed date

Tags: date, batch-file

I have a batch file that needs to see if a set date has passed.

Example:

```
 ::The set date is in a file Date.txt
 ::Format is mm\dd\yy
 for /f %%d in (date.txt) do (
 set date_fixed=%%d
     )
 [do condition to see if todays date is greater than the set date]
```

And Date.txt reads: 06/03/2015

Comment: I would recommend that ISO-8601 date formatting always be used. It is much easier to work with and will even sort without changes. In order to get the current date, I would use gettimestamp.bat from http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=42034#p42034

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare date in Batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373460/how-to-compare-date-in-batch-script)

Comment: [There are lots](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+compare+date) of similar questions. Please use search before asking.